# Please help me identify this IC with the markings `0300 1942 FUV`

Tags: identification

Where can I find information about this IC? I have tried Octopart and also DatasheetCatalog.

The IC is marked `0300 1942 FUV` but I can not seem to find it online:

[image: The IC is marked 0300 1942 FUV but I can not seem to find it online]

Comment: Asking for datasheets specifically is considered off-topic. Do you know what this IC is, part number, etc? If not, identification questions are allowed, so I'd advice you to change the question. Usually datasheets are easy to find if you know the manufacturer and part number. However, if you want identification you will likely need to provide more information, like where this IC came from and what it is used for.

Comment: @nanash1 _"Asking for datasheets specifically is considered off-topic."_ Can you provide a source for this claim? I couldn't find anything [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) or [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Velvel [Here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/how-to-deal-with-datasheet-requests) & [And an example of a closed question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670091/i-need-a-datasheet-for-an-ic-of-28-pin-550-7-dimension-with-top-marking-cbkdnq)

Comment: @nanash1 Thanks for the reference! I find it humorous that *`help me identify xxx`* is on-topic, while *`help me find the datasheet of xxx`* is off-topic. In essence both requests are the same, just framed differently.

Comment: @Velvel I agree. The rule is also not communicated very well and enforced pretty arbitrarily from what I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

SOIC-8 with a thick package is probably an optocoupler, so this one is likely to be the [HCPL-0300](https://www.broadcom.com/products/optocouplers/industrial-plastic/digital-optocouplers/8mbd/hcpl-0300) ([datasheet](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-0919EN)).

[image: HCPL-0300 functional diagram]